# Intersection of a plane with surface of ListSurfacePlot3d

Tags: data-visualization, wolfram-mathematica

If I have a list of points in 3D space that are only roughly located on a surface, this surface can be visualized with `ListSurfacePlot3D` in Mathematica. How can I find the intersection of this approximate surface with a plane, that spans between two vectors u and v? And to continue this, how would I find the intersection of the resulting line with another plane that spans between two vectors m and n?

The dataset of points is available here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/rlj91jrh1bp4g2c/data.txt?dl=0

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/206651/58370).